# ssh to / from Jenkins to a docker container

Tags: docker, jenkins

I'm running a centOS8 linux container and I want to continuously update a .jar file inside
that container which runs centOS8. To update that .jar I want to set up a job in Jenkins and Jenkins is spinning on the separate host (not as a docker container).

So. Basically I think I want to create a job which would ssh from Jenkins to a Docker container and would execute the changes related to a .jar file. Is this possible?

Comment: The normal Docker process would be to build a new image with the updated jar file, then delete the existing container and run a new container based on the new image.  That avoids needing to modify the contents of a running container, and it avoids a huge amount of hassle around securely getting a shell in a running container.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I just don't want to install / configure separate servers /hosts, so I thought to use docker as a lightweight VM.

Comment: A better model might be to think about a Docker as a wrapper around a _process_.  If you ran `java -jar something.jar`, how would you update the jar file, or ssh into the process?  You'd probably just start a new JVM with the updated jar instead; in the same way, standard Docker process would be to run a new container.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I totally agree with you. But for my test environment (I want to test Jenkins - Ansible - Host interaction) I don't want to install / configure hosts or VMs, so I thought maybe I could do what I want to do using Docker containers.